# WPF StreamWriter error

Tags: c#, wpf

When I want to write a file I get this error:

System.ArgumentNullException: Value can't be null.
Parameter name: path
in System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
in System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path)
in Music_Player.Library.SongList_Save(String fileName) in "MY PATH"

This is the code of file writer:

```
private void AddSong(string path)
    {
        DataContext = new Song();
        Song _songAdd = new Song();
        FileInfo _song = new FileInfo(path);


        _songAdd.SongLengh = MainWindow._MusicPlayer.TransformToTime(MainWindow._MusicPlayer.GetSongMaxLength(path));
        _songAdd.SongName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_song.Name);
        _songAdd.SongPath = path;
        LB_SongList.Items.Add(_songAdd);
        SongList_Save(SelectedPlaylist);
    }
private void LB_SongList_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        String[] file = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as String[];
        foreach (var path in file)
        {
            if (MainWindow._MusicPlayer.GetSongMaxLength(path) != -1)
            {
                AddSong(path);
            }
        }
    }

public void SongList_Save(String fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) && File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                using (StreamWriter comboboxsw = new StreamWriter(fileName))
                {
                    for (int cfgitem = 0; cfgitem < LB_SongList.Items.Count; cfgitem++)
                    {
                        comboboxsw.WriteLine(GetPath((ListBoxItem)(LB_SongList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(cfgitem))));
                    }
                    comboboxsw.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And if this isn't enough it does write a file, but the text is written twice.
//Edit it writes twice but it could be caused by other code so nevermind.

New exception:
System.ArgumentNullException: Value can't be null.
Parameter name: element

in MS.Interal.Media.VisualTreeUtils.AsNonNullVisual(DependencyObject element, Visual& visual, Visual3D& visual3D)

in System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChildernCount(DependencyObject reference)

in Music_Player.Library.FindVisualChild[childItem](DependencyObject obj) in "MY PATH"

in Music_Player.Library.GetPath(ListBoxItem lb) in "MY PATH"

in Music_Player.Library.SongList_Save(String fileName) in "MY PATH"

All three methods below:

```
private childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj) where childItem : DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if (child != null && child is childItem)
                return (childItem)child;
            else
            {
                childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);
                if (childOfChild != null)
                    return childOfChild;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
private string GetPath(ListBoxItem lb)
    {
        ListBoxItem myListBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)(lb);
        ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(myListBoxItem);
        DataTemplate myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
        Label target = (Label)myDataTemplate.FindName("SongPath", myContentPresenter);
        return (string)target.Content;
    }
public void SongList_Save(String fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            {
                using (StreamWriter comboboxsw = new StreamWriter(fileName))
                {
                    for (int cfgitem = 0; cfgitem < LB_SongList.Items.Count; cfgitem++)
                    {
                        comboboxsw.WriteLine(GetPath((ListBoxItem)(LB_SongList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(cfgitem))));
                    }
                    comboboxsw.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Easy one, debug your application and you'll see, that `fileName` is null or empty as the exception already pointed out... ;)

Comment: But I always define fileName when calling. And it writes the file with the name it should and write 2 same lines.

Comment: Well the exception is telling otherwise. Check your code.

Comment: @KubaWasilczyk see the updated answer below.. Though, are you trying to update an existing file or do you want a new file created everytime you do a write?

Comment: Both. If file exist it should delete old one and write new one. Or when doesn't exist create one.

Comment: @KubaWasilczyk okay, that's the default behavior of streamwriter. Are you still seeing the null exception?

Comment: Yes. It still gives me exception. This time with parameter name: element still can't be null.

Comment: can you please post the new exception

Comment: Done. Added code from exception too.

Comment: Really noone can help me? I'm thinking why its doing this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like path is `null`. try checking for `null` before you use it.

```
public void SongList_Save(String fileName)
{
    try
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
            using (StreamWriter comboboxsw = new StreamWriter(fileName))
            {
                for (int cfgitem = 0; cfgitem < LB_SongList.Items.Count; cfgitem++)
                {
                    comboboxsw.WriteLine(GetPath((ListBoxItem)(LB_SongList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(cfgitem))));
                }
                comboboxsw.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: If the file doesn't exist, the code wouldn't write anything, although it would work. Omit the `File.Exists(...)` part and everything will be fine.

Comment: Still same thing. I will add another piece of code that could cause it.

Comment: @DHN yeah, just realized new files were being creating instead of existing ones being updated. Thanks!